# XSD Schema - Sequence and List for checkboxes

Tags: xml, xsd

I got a small confusion for `XSD schema`. I need to cover checkboxes (i.e. multiple values per element). see below:

[1]

```
<xsd:element name="Parent">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element maxOccurs="2" minOccurs="0" name="Children">
    <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Child" type="xsd:string">
      .
      .
```

This means we can have:

```
<parent>
 <children>
  <child />
 </children> 
 <children>
  <child />
 </children> 
</parent>
```

---

Now can the same be defined and achieved with **`<xsd:list>`**?
like this:

```
<xsd:element name="Parent">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Children">    

    <xsd:simpleType>
     <xsd:list>
      <xsd:simpleType>
       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">    
        <xsd:enumeration value="Child 1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="Child 2"/>    
       </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
     </xsd:list>
    </xsd:simpleType>

   </xsd:element>
```

---

So, overall I am a bit confused between `xsd:list` and `minOccurs/maxOccurs`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`xsd:list`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256162.aspx) element defines the possible values, not the possible child elements - your second example defines an element `Children` that has as valid content a space-separated list of the strings `Child 1` and `Child 2` - i.e. an XML like this:

```
<Parent>
   <Children>Child 1</Children>
 </Parent>
```

or

```
<Parent>
   <Children>Child 2</Children>
 </Parent>
```

or

```
<Parent>
   <Children>Child 1 Child 2</Children>
 </Parent>
```

Note also that the values in a list defined with `xsd:list` are space-separated, so they should not contain spaces.

Comment: ok that makes more sense. So you mean to say, with `xsd:list`, it will take multiple values as space separated? (just like a CSV)?

Comment: Yes, it will take multiple space-separated values of the specified base simple type. In a CSV instead the values are comma-separated.